# Bamboo maven release plugin with git on windows

Tags: git, maven, bamboo

When bamboo executes the maven build plugin it's stuck on git push to push the pom changes it did. It's because it prompts for the password everytime.

I've tried SSH with a SSH-AGENT but it does not work.

I've searched everywhere and tried everything I can think of, what am I missing here?

Comment: Obvious test to run: If you can find a way to push to that repository using the regular git command line tool without stopping for a password prompt, the problem involves only Maven or specifically Bamboo, not your client and server Git configuration.

Comment: I think it's because the ssh-agent is configured with the git bash but bamboo uses the maven command in default windows prompt.